# Combine two json sections into one json object

Tags: javascript, json

I would like to combine topData and bottomData into completeData.

```
var topData = {
    "auth": "1vmPoG22V3qqf43mPeMc",
    "property" : "ATL-D406",  
    "status" : 1,
    "user" : "test001@aaa.com",
    "name" : "Abraham Denson"
}

var bottomData = {
    "agent" : "pusher@agent.com",
    "agency" : "Thai Tims Agency",
    "agentCommission" : 1000,
    "arrival" : "arrive 12pm at condo",
    "departure" : "leaving room at 6pm",
}

var completeData = topData.concat(bottomData)
```

Since these are not arrays, concat wont work here.

Can this be done without making foreach loops?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [`Object.assign()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) to concatenate your objects.

```
var newObj = Object.assign({}, topData, bottomData)
```

---

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign):

> The `Object.assign()` method is used to copy the values of all
>   enumerable own properties from one or more source objects to a target
>   object. It will return the target object.

---

```js
var topData = {
    "auth": "1vmPoG22V3qqf43mPeMc",
    "property" : "ATL-D406",  
    "status" : 1,
    "user" : "test001@aaa.com",
    "name" : "Abraham Denson"
}

var bottomData = {
    "agent" : "pusher@agent.com",
    "agency" : "Thai Tims Agency",
    "agentCommission" : 1000,
    "arrival" : "arrive 12pm at condo",
    "departure" : "leaving room at 6pm",
}

var completeData = Object.assign({}, topData, bottomData);

console.log(completeData);
```

Comment: That did the trick, thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can use [**Object.assign**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign).

```js
var topData = {
  "auth": "1vmPoG22V3qqf43mPeMc",
  "property": "ATL-D406",
  "status": 1,
  "user": "test001@aaa.com",
  "name": "Abraham Denson"
}

var bottomData = {
  "agent": "pusher@agent.com",
  "agency": "Thai Tims Agency",
  "agentCommission": 1000,
  "arrival": "arrive 12pm at condo",
  "departure": "leaving room at 6pm",
}

var completeData = Object.assign(topData, bottomData);
console.log(completeData)
```

It return the target object which mean properties from `bottomData` will be added to `topData`

Comment: This will mutate `topData`, which is probably not what the OP wants.

Comment: Yep, that did it :)

Answer (score 0):

```
var completeData = {...topData, ...bottomData};
```

This is [**object spread syntax**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator).